# iOS. How can I speed up cell deletion animation from a table?

Tags: ios, performance, animation

How can I speed up cell deletion animation from a table? An example of a quick removal can be seen in the standard Mail application on iOS.

Comment: How much time does your deletion takes ?

Comment: Standard 0.2 second

Comment: How much faster do you want ? Never calculated before but even iPhone mail takes >= this time.

Comment: About 0.05 - 0.1 second, or faster so like in standard Mail iOS app.

Comment: How did you calculate this time for iPhone mail ?

Comment: No, but it's clearly faster than the standard code allows.

Comment: This can never happen unless you are performing some background task while deleting the item which is taking too much time. Check your code for this.
Also, I would like to see a comparison of the time for both your and mail app delete animation. So please upload a video/gif featuring that comparison.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165939/discussion-between-mikhail-s-and-nitish).